# Unauthorized (401) Power BI Embedded using the samples Node and .NET

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

When running the examples of [embedded for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=node-js#step-8---embed-your-content) applications (both Node and .NET), I get this error (in the console is coming from `/getEmbedToken`)

```json
Status: Unauthorized (401)
Response: {"error":{"code":"PowerBINotAuthorizedException","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBINotAuthorizedException","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
RequestId: fe5ca8dd-a49e-41b0-8f08-**********
```

- The report I embedded is visible from Power BI service (app.powerbi.com)

I have tried:

- Made sure config.json and web.config have the right information (clientId, reportId, tenantId, etc)
- The authenticationMode is ServicePrincipal, and I'm using the credentials of the Global Admin (same user that created the dataset, report, has all permissions, is App Registration Owner, etc.)
- All permissions granted on Power BI REST APIs on the App Registration
- Workspace access is enabled
- I'm using a Pro trial and have not used any [developer tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/available-features/available-features-get-available-features) yet (`"usage": 0`)
- The [dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-dataset) is not requiring effective identity (`"isEffectiveIdentityRequired": false`)

Has anyone any clue of what else to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the license mode of the workspace - is it `Pro`, `Premium per user`, `Premium per capacity` or `Embedded`? See [Assigning workspaces to capacities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-capacity-manage#assigning-workspaces-to-capacities).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. In case this happens to anybody, here's the solution:

The problem was in Step 7 - [Enable workspace access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=node-js#step-7---enable-workspace-access) that states *Sign in to Power BI service > workspace you want to enable > Workspace access > Access pane, > copy the service principal to the Enter email address text box.*

Because the email of the global admin was already filled out, I overlooked the actual requirement of **entering the service principal** ("Enter email address" was confusing).

The name of the service principal is the Display Name of the Azure AD app, as it appears in the Azure AD app's overview tab. This could also be a security group if you defined any.